# underscorejs not defined when loading with XMLHttpRequest and eval

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I am trying to load underscorejs using XMLHttpRequest and eval

```
function includeScriptSync(scriptUrl)
{
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.open("GET", scriptUrl, false);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if ((xmlhttp.status == 200) && (xmlhttp.readyState == 4))
        {
            eval(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.send();
}
includeScriptSync("jquery.min.js");
includeScriptSync('underscore-min.js');
includeScriptSync('jquery.watermark.min.js');
includeScriptSync('polyfills.js');

console.log(_); //here jQuery is defined but underscore is not defined(i.e. typeof of _ === "undefined")
```

but in the end underscore is not defined although jQuery is loaded.

Any ideas why underscore js loading fails ?

I'm using Underscore 1.5.1 and jQuery 1.9.1

EDIT: I added 2 more plugins for jQuery and they are loaded.

`$(this).watermark`  is defined , as well for polyfills

Comment: Where are you adding the new `<script>` to the DOM? You are saying `console.log($);` is not `undefined`?

Comment: as far as i know, eval executes the code in the global scope. What I'm saying is that _ is not defined when console.log line is executed but jquery is defined

Comment: Why use XHR and `eval` when you could just do `var s = document.createElement('script'); s.src = scriptUrl;` ? [edited: original comment assumed async XHR, I've just noticed you use synchronous request]

Comment: from the beginning it was sync request :)

Comment: I assume you've checked for JS errors? Could it be your copy of the library is corrupted? (yes, I know... but it's worth ruling it out)

Comment: i checked that, the file looks fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the `onreadystatechange` handler is getting fired?

If you want to make a synchronous request, you shouldn't listen for events, try this instead:

```
function includeScriptSync(scriptUrl)
{
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open('GET', scriptUrl, false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
        eval(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
```

Comment: "The includeScriptSync() you defined, is not synchronous" — isn't it? What is the `false` doing in the line `xmlhttp.open("GET", scriptUrl, false);` then?

Comment: @Quentin Wow I just overlooked it because I saw this line: `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()`. OP is doing it wrong then, I will update my answer.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Example.3A_HTTP_synchronous_request , "false" = sync

Comment: it seems fardjad solution is good for me in the end, looks like send(null) does the trick